# Does Python implement short-circuiting in built-in functions such as min()?

Tags: python-3.x, function, boolean-logic, built-in

Does **Python 3** implement **short-circuiting** in built-in functions whenever possible, just like it does for boolean statements?

A specific example, take the below code snippet:

```
min((20,11), key = lambda x : x % 10) # 20
```

Does Python evaluate beforehand that the minimum value possible of the function passed as the *key* argument is 0, and therefore stops right after evaluating the first integer in the iterable passed (20) as 20 % 10 is equal to 0?
Or does it have to evaluate all the elements in the iterable before returning the answer?

I guess short-circuiting isn't even always possible especially for more complex functions, but what about for well-known, built-in functions or operators like ***%***?

I couldn't find the answer in the official docs.

Thanks,

Comment: You can check it yourself by looking at how its implemented. Check min_max function at - https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Python/bltinmodule.c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

python has to evaluate all values inside the iterable because the languaje evaluate element by element, if you have in your tuple something that is not a number it will trigger an exception when try to perform the % operation. Python can not guess what is inside your list. You can test this by defining a function instead of a lambda and set debug point inside.

```py
def my_mod(x): 
    import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace() 
    return x % 20
```

then call the function

```py
min((20,11), key = my_mod)
```

you can do a quick error test case with

```py
min((20,11, "s"), key = my_mod)
```

It will trigger an exception but first had to evaluate all the previous element in the list.